# VS for Mac 2022 - how do I turn off squiggly green lines

Tags: visual-studio-mac-2022

I did something to my project and now nearly every line in every .cs file has a squiggly green line at the beginning of each line. I believe it might be indicating it doesn't like my formatting because the project compiles with no errors and the little lightbulb says IDE0055 Fix formatting.

[Now all my .cs files look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zfhcb.png)

I have been unable to find the option that turns this off and on.